# Upload XML no Codeignter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, xml, upload

To fazendo um upload no codeigniter 3 e ele não está aceitando xml para enviar. Ele me mostra um erro que o tipo do arquivo selecionado não é permitido.

```
$config['upload_path']          = './uploads';
$config['allowed_types']        = 'xml';
$config['max_size']             = 0;
$config['max_width']            = 0;
$config['max_height']           = 0;
$config['encrypt_name']         = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('nota_fiscal'))
    {
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
```

Meu arquivo mimes.php está assim:

```
'xml'   =>  array('application/xml', 'text/xml', 'text/plain'),
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366558/codeigniter-xml-file-not-uploading

Comment: já vi isso e não resolveu, o mimes.php do codeigniter3 já vem desse jeito.

Comment: E se tu substituir no mimes essa atribuição do xml pra essa: `'xml'    =>    array('text/xml','application/xml','application/octet-stream')` ?

Comment: Consegui fazer funcionar desse jeito, valeuu!!